# O que são e como funcionam registradores?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-computadores

> Os processadores de mercado apresentam um conjunto de componentes e
>   elementos internos, os quais realizam funções específicas. Destes
>   componentes, os registradores executam importantes funções no
>   processamento das instruções.

Como funcionam esses registradores MDR (*Memory Data Register*), IR (*Instruction Register*) e CP (*Program Counter*)?

Comment: Se você não sabe o que é esse RI, imagina a gente que nem viu o resto do exercício.