# Qual a menor unidade de memória de um processador?

Tags: memória, ciência-da-computação, arquitetura-computadores

Eu queria saber qual a menor unidade de memória do processador? Será os registradores de dados ou existe algo menor que eles?

Comment: Defina memória. Dê um contento do que quer saber.

Comment: de todo o processador mesmo, quero saber se o registrador é a menor unidade.

Comment: Eu diria que qualquer componente que tenha a capacidade de armazenar um **bit** `0` ou `1`, poderia ser considerado a "menor unidade de memoria" já que o [tag:bit] é a menor informação que podemos armazenar.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara e eu diria que possui uma relação direta com esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203733/5878).

Comment: @caiojuniors A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

O único local onde tem uma informação da aplicação no processador efetivo é o registrador, então é a menor e a maior unidade.

Hoje os processadores são mais complexos e possuem registradores especializados, desde 1 bit até valores altos (512 por exemplo). Nas arquiteturas mais comuns hoje em dia os registrados gerais costumam ter 32 ou 64 bits.

Os processadores atuais costumam ter memória cache, aí sim podemos chamar de memória (dãã). É pouco complicado falar sobre ela porque espelha a memória principal, dependendo de como definir. Pode ser 1 bit, ou pode ser 1 byte (acho a mais intuitiva), ou o tamanho do *cache line*, em geral 64 bytes. Pode ser que tenha um definição formal, mas desconheço. Mas isto não é o processador mesmo, só está no mesmo *chip*.

Se não definir bem o que deseja saber pode acabar sabendo o que não deseja, e nem perceber.